# Could resnet handles "one image" to "multiple ouputs" task?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am not doing image classification. I need a model which take one image as input and ouput multiple values (all values could be larger than 1). Could resnet50 be used for this task?

I checked the resnet50 code in pytorch. Resnet50 does not end up with softmax, therefore, I guess resnet50 could be used for the task.

I have trained a raw model using resnet50 for "1 image to multiple value" task. Loss is defined as the mean square error between the predicted values and answers. The result is pretty good actually. But I am wondering since resnet50 is designed for image classification (which to my knowledge is a singe output task), how could it also be used for multiple outputs task

Comment: By all values could be larger than 1, do you mean they are integers? Counts? (It doesn't affect the answer to your main question, but their distribution definitely affects the choice of loss function, and if you should scale or not.)

Comment: Image to bounding box models might be worth a look. They take an image, and output coordinates of bounding boxes. E.g. https://towardsdatascience.com/bounding-box-prediction-from-scratch-using-pytorch-a8525da51ddc

Answer (score 1):

Resnet is designed for image classification, but under the hood the whole process can be summarized as a two-step-process: First the network extracts image features, then it performs classification based on these features. In a traditional image classification task, image features can be things like mean brightness or colour distributions, for a convolutional neural network these features are much more abstract and it is much more difficult to describe what the neural network sees as a feature.
Feature extraction generally works on any type of images. If you use the pretrained network that comes with pytorch, you don't even have to train the whole network again, you can simply remove the last layer that performs classification and attach your own classifier instead. In training you freeze the first n-1 layers and only train the last layer with that satisfies your multi-output needs.
This process of taking a network that was trained on one task and tweaking it slightly to apply it to a different but very similar task is also called `Transfer Learning`. You might want to read up on this, for example on wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning

Comment: Thanks for your explain. I am not using pretrained network. I have a huge data set and plan to train a new model from zero. Since training all the dataset will cost me a lot of times. I am wondering is resnet a good choice for "one image" to "several outputs" tasks? (I am pretty new to deep learning area. sorry for my naive question )

Comment: will any other kown model do this job better than resnet?

Comment: Yes, you can use resnet for your task, if your dataset is large enough. Most model architectures that are considered state of the art are probably working well for this. You can see here for a list of models with performance on imagenet: https://paperswithcode.com/sota/image-classification-on-imagenet

Comment: What about the loss function? I think crossenropy is a good pick when I am dealing with probability distribution task, such as image classification.  But all my output are larger than 1. Is crossenropy is a good choice for my task? Currently, I am using mean square error between prediciton and answers.

Comment: Cross entropy is meant to compare two probabilities or distributions of probabilities. You should either rescale your results or use a different loss function.